# Adding data from python script into mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why the data that my python script has gathered  is not being input into the mysql database properly

Here is my code

```
/*** index is a dictionary that has the struture: 
     index = {links:[words], links: [words],.......} ***/
#There are multiple items in words

for k, v in index.iteritems():
    links = str(k)
    words  = str(v) [1:-1]
    import MySQLdb

    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","my_db" )

    cursor = db.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(('insert into SITE(url, keywords) values("%s", "%s")' % \
         (links,words)))
        db.commit()
    except:
        db.rollback()


db.close()
```

Each row in my table should have two feilds: url and keywords
Instead of insterting 6 rows it only inserts two.
Please help?!

Comment: please show the contents of ´index´

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is a problem, because you open a new connection for every item. Then you shouldn't format values into a SQL-statement, use parameters instead. Third, you shouldn't ignore exceptions, because then, you cannot figure out, what's going wrong. The representation of a list is nothing, to work with in production code, use join instead

```
import logging
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","my_db" )
for links, words in index.iteritems():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute('insert into SITE(url, keywords) values(%s, %s)', (links, ','.join(words)))
        db.commit()
    except Exception:
        logging.exception('insert went wrong')
        db.rollback()
db.close()
```